# Importance of Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Currently I have come across a function which represents the profit that is made when a order sizes is made and sold, this being revenue - cost of production where:
$$ \text{Revenue} = 200x-0.50x^2 $$
$$ \text{Cost} = 59.88+0.10x+0.02x^2 $$
From this information I have come to this formula for Profit:
$$ P=-59.88+199.9x-0.52x^2 $$
where, x=order size
From this I have derived it to find the marginal profit by letting dp/dx=0 but I do not really know the significance of the function

$$ \frac{dp}{dx}= \frac{dr}{dx}-\frac{dc}{dx}=0 $$

Could someone please explain.

Comment: You calculate the $x$-value of the critical point of the parabola. Since $x^2$ has a negative coefficient (-0.52) the parabola opens downward. Thus the extreme point is a **maximum**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, we want to maximize the profits. By Fermat's theorem, the extrema of a function will appear at a critical point, which in this case is the point where the derivative is zero.
I recommend reading the Wikipedia article:
[enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima)

Answer (score 2):

You have a function for profit that looks like this...[image]

The profit is on the Y-axis. As you can see, it is maximum where the graph is at its peak (its turning point), this is where $dP/dx=0$ as you suggested. So to carry on with the calculations you need to differentiate the function for P and find where it is 0 and this is the optimum order size.

Hope this helps!